# How to update a List in C#

Tags: c#

```
IList<ReceiptAllocationMaster> objReceiptMaster = (IList<ReceiptAllocationMaster>)Session["AllocationResult"];

public class ReceiptAllocationMaster
{
    public string application { get; set; }

    public List<Users> users { get; set; }
}

public class Users
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public string surname { get; set; }
}
```

I need to Update the above list with some value where `application = "applicationame"` and users where `surname = "surname"` into the same list.

Comment: did u mean you want to update only those items of the list where `application="applicationname"` ? also, update a list means what? which properties of the classes you want to update?

Comment: Yes i want to update those items where application="applicationname". and want to update in the same IList the i have declared. and want to update the properties of User class

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over your list and modify matched items:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < objReceiptMaster.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = objReceiptMaster[i];
            if (item.application == "applicationname" && item.users.Any(x => x.surname == "surname"))
                objReceiptMaster[i] = new ReceiptAllocationMaster();
        }
```

Instead of `new ReceiptAllocationMaster()` you can write any modification data logic.

Comment: Here my user class is having One more property as:

public class Users
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public string surname { get; set; }

    public List<Item> users { get; set; }

}


public class Item
{
  public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

And I need to update the Item class property inside objReceiptMaster

Comment: Just select "selected" user and modify its properties: objReceiptMaster[i].users.First(x => x.surname == "surname").users = new Item();

Comment: Hi, your point is correct .But as i mentioned now ..my user class is having one more class property as Item. I need to add one more condition as Id="123" in the select list.

Answer (score 0):

though your question is not clear, this shd give u some idea:

```
objReceiptMaster.Where(x=>x.application=="applicationname" && 
                          x.users.Any(d=>d.surname=="surname"))
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(item=>{//update your list
                           item.application = "whatever value";  

                           item.users.ForEach(user=>{//update users 

                               user.name="whatever username";
                          });   
                      });
```

Comment: Hi, Manish your suggestion is correct . But there are few changes in my reqirement. Can you please check the below code and give some valuable suggestion

Comment: @santoshparida first of all, you shd not create a separate answer to add to your question. here on Stackoverflow, always update your question if you have any thing more to add to it. Second, still it doesn't change anything, my code was just a sample to make u see how to access properties, and is still fit for your new changes. just update the properties name whereever you are using it. We cannot spoon feed you santosh